# Why key is nil in context.valueCtx?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

For the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

// TraceID represents the trace id
type TraceID string

// TraceIDKey is the type of value to use for the key. The key is
// type specific and only values of the same type will match
type TraceIDKey int

func main() {
    // Create a traceID for this request
    traceID1 := TraceID("f47ac10b-58cc-0372-8567-0e02b2c3d479")
    traceID2 := TraceID("aaaac10b-58cc-0372-8567-0e02b2c3d479")

        const traceIDKey1 TraceIDKey = 1

    const traceIDKey2 TraceIDKey = 2

    // Store the traceID value inside the context with a value of
    // zero for the key type
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx1 := context.WithValue(ctx, traceIDKey1, traceID1) // Line 28
    ctx2 := context.WithValue(ctx1, traceIDKey2, traceID2)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ctx)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ctx1)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ctx2)
}
```

---

key shows `nil`(as shown below) for Line 28:

[image]

But, we set the key as `const traceIDKey1 TraceIDKey = 1`. So, am expecting the `key` as `1`. Correct me.

---

```
// context.go
type valueCtx struct {
    Context
    key, val interface{}
}
```

Why `key` is `nil` in `valueCtx`? using VSCode

Comment: Are you looking at the correct context?  You have 3 contexts here: `ctx2` is the outer one, inside is `ctx1`, then inside is `ctx` created with `context.Background()`. The inner one does not have any data.

Comment: @TehSphinX Please check the query updated with `ctx`, `ctx1` & `ctx2`

Comment: It still says on the parent of the `key:  nil` line:  `context.emptyCtx`. That is the context.Background(). It returns `background` which is defined as `new(emptyCtx)`: https://golang.org/src/context/context.go?s=7426:7451#L198

Comment: @ThinkGoodly Debug watch with vscode and you will see that

Comment: @overexchange: yes that seems strange how VSCode shows that...

Answer (score 0):

The most inner context is created with `context.Background()` and does not have data, nor a key.

Not sure what tool you used for that screenshot, but Goland does not show data and key fields for the most inner context:

[image]

Edit: it seems like VSCode creates some confusing output here. The `key: nil` line is a child of `Context <context.Context(*context.emptyCtx)>`. That is the context created with `context.Background()` which returns a `*context.emptyCtx`. See [here](https://golang.org/src/context/context.go?#L198)